# J'ai bien peur que tu n'aies raison : faut-il mettre le mot « ne » ?

Tags: grammaire, négation, adverbes, ne-explétif

Doit-on dire :

> J'ai bien peur que tu aies raison.

ou

> J'ai bien peur que tu n'aies raison.

---

Should the word *ne* be used in the sentence above? What's the difference?

Comment: This could do with being a more generic question about when to use 'ne' on its own, without a 'paired' word like 'pas', 'plus', 'que', etc.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Les deux formes sont correctes. La deuxième est une figure de style appelée le « ne [explétif](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expl%C3%A9tif) » ou « semi-négation » (voir [grammaire.reverso.net](http://grammaire.reverso.net/3_1_40_ne_expletif.shtml) et [lawlessfrench.com](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/ne-expletif/)).

Ce « ne » n'a pas de sens négatif et n'a pas de caractère obligatoire.

---

Both forms are correct. In the second form, *ne* is an [expletive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_expletive). It has no negative connotation and is not compulsory.

Comment: Un exemple: “Avant que le volcan n’ait trouvé son issue,
Avant que tu n’aies mis la main à ta massue, Tu te prends à sourire et tu dis : À quoi bon ?” (Victor Hugo, *Dédain*)

Comment: En anglais, ce phénomène s'appele ['pleonastic ne'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm#Syntactic_pleonasm)

Comment: @lkl Why do you replace links to French.thought.co by lawlessfrench?

Comment: I wrote all of these lessons (Thoughtco was originally About and I was the French Guide there for 15 years). After I left, my lessons were edited by random people who didn't necessarily speak French - many errors were introduced which I cannot fix and no one there cares to. Therefore, I think it's important to update the links to my current, accurate lessons at LawlessFrench. Since I'm the author of both, I believe this is acceptable.

Comment: @lkl I agree. Thank you for explaining! Cheers.

Answer (score 17):

[L'un ou l'autre se dit ou se disent](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominique_Bouhours#cite_note-0), mais ici il y a une différence de niveau de langue. Il s'agit d'un [« ne explétif »](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expl%C3%A9tif), qui s'emploie dans des propositions au subjonctif qui concernent un fait avéré mais sont le complément d'un verbe ou d'un adjectif qui a une connotation négative (« avoir peur », « douter »). Le « ne » est assez souvent utilisé dans un registre soutenu, et quasiment jamais dans un registre familier. Le [Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ne) analyse cet usage (article « ne », partie III).

---

Both sentences are correct and they have the same meaning. This is an [expletive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_expletive) use of the word *[ne](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ne)*, unrelated to its use as a [negation](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/301/lusage-de-ne-sans-un-mot-associe). The expletive *ne* can be used in clauses that are in the subjunctive mood and, often, are a complement of a verb or adjective with a negative connotation. This use of *ne* is very common in formal speech and rare in colloquial speech.

Answer (score 10):

Le "ne" explétif est facultatif, dans ce cas-ci.

d'après Le Petit Grevisse:

> **Verbes de crainte**
>  Après les verbes de crainte pris affirmativement, on
>   met ordinairement 'ne' quand la subordonée exprime un effet que l'on
>   craint de voir se produire.
>   *Je crains que l'ennemi ne vienne.
>
>   Je redoute, j'ai peur, j'appréhende qu'un malheur ne vous arrive.*

Comment: Le ne explétif est, pour la plupart du temps, facultatif sauf au cas où c'est une comparaison:

Elle dort plus que je ne mange ... (etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Additions to the previous remarks : 
1 - "**tu aies**" is an unpleasant hiatus in French.
2 - the expletive "ne" is a copy of Latin, such as in "Timeo ne veniat", "J'ai peur qu'il ne vienne", meaning than I am afraid that he could come, and not that he won't turn up.
Ex. : Autour de 1810, les Britanniques craignaient que Napoléon **ne** débarquât.

Comment: There's just nothing wrong with “tu aies”. The *nē* from Latin became the French *ne explétif*, whereas the Latin *nōn* became the French *ne* that you traditionally find in negated sentences. You're not providing an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: Le Français déchiffré, clé du langage et des langues. Henri Adamcweski

Ce ne qui en dit long pages 173 à 183.
Le NE dit explétif pages 176 à 180

Answer (score -3):

"J'ai bien peur que tu dises la vérité" et non pas "J'ai bien peur que tu ne dises la vérité".

On a peur de la vérité de la seconde proposition, il faut donc éviter la "semi-négation". En revanche on peut dire "J'ai bien peur que tu ne dises pas la vérité", ou "J'ai bien peur que tu n'aies pas raison".

Comment: J'éviterais "J'ai bien peur que tu n'aies pas raison". Les double négations rendent la compréhension très compliquée.

Comment: "Je n'ai pas peur que tu n'aies pas raison" est une double négation, mais la phrase d'exemple citée n'en est pas une.