# L'usage de « ne » sans un mot associé ?

Tags: grammaire, usage, négation

Généralement, quand on voit *ne* dans une phrase, ce mot est associé avec un autre mot, pour modifier une verbe ; par exemple :

> il ne parle pas…
>
> il ne parle plus…
>
> il ne parle que…

Mais j'ai déjà vu *ne* (ou *n'*) tout seul ; par exemple dans « personne n'est parfait ».

Que veut dire le *n'* dans ce contexte ?  Est-ce qu'il est simplement pour accentuer ? Est-il optionnel ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/135/doit-on-dire-jai-bien-peur-que-tu-aies-raison-ou-jai-bien-peur-que-tu-naie

Comment: Je doute que le _ne_ dans _personne n'est parfait_ soit explétif (on ne peut pas dire _personne est parfait_), et donc c'est une question différente.

Comment: @Brennan This is not a duplicate, both because the earlier question is a little specialized and because there is a specific confusion underlying Jez's example that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Il y a trois manières de former une phrase négative en français.

- Avec **« ne » seulement**. C'est un usage **vielli**, qui ne se rencontre plus de nos jours sauf dans quelques expressions figées (qui elles-même appartiennent en général à la langue soutenue). Voir la partie I.A de [l'entrée du TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ne).

  > Fabrice revint sur la grande route, où il n'y avait toujours âme qui vive. [Stendhal]
- Avec **« ne » et un auxiliaire négatif** ; c'est la **manière normale** de former une négation en français. La forme la plus courante est « ne ... pas » (simple négation) ; il y a d'autre mots négatifs qui apportent une nuance de sens : « ne ... plus » (c'était vrai dans le passé, c'est faux maintenant), « ne ... jamais » (ce n'est pas vrai ni maintenant, ni à un autre moment), « ne ... personne » (ce n'est pas vrai ni de toi, ni de moi, ni de Pierre, ni de Paul, …), « ne ... que ... » (ce n'est pas vrai, sauf avec la restriction qui suit le « que »), etc. Voir la partie II.B de [l'entrée du TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ne) (et la partie II pour « ne ... que »).

  > Je n'ai vu passer personne.
- Avec **seulement un auxiliaire négatif**, c'est-à-dire en omettant le mot « ne ». Cette forme est relativement moderne appartient exclusivement au langage **familier**, parlé.

  > J'ai pas dit ça ! J'ai vu personne !

La phrase « personne n'est parfait » est une phrase négative qui suit la construction normale. Le pronom « personne » est un auxiliaire négatif, qui a ici la fonction grammaticale de sujet. On pourrait en principe dire « personne est parfait » en langage familier, mais sur cet exemple, ça passe mal, je pense parce que c'est une expression figée.

Parce que ce n'était pas assez confus comme ça, il existe un autre sens du mot « ne » qui ne, lui aussi vielli (mais encore utilisé dans la langue soutenue) qui change pas le sens de la phrase. Cela s'appelle le [« **ne explétif** »](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expl%C3%A9tif). Il s'emploie dans des propositions au subjonctif qui concernent un fait avéré mais sont le complément d'un verbe ou d'un adjectif qui a une connotation négative (« avoir peur », « douter »). La partie III de [l'entrée du TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ne) explique cet usage. Voir aussi la question « [J'ai bien peur que tu n'aies raison : faut-il mettre le mot « ne » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/135/doit-on-dire-jai-bien-peur-que-tu-aies-raison-ou-jai-bien-peur-que-tu-naie) » sur ce site pour un exemple.

Comment: "La phrase « personne n'est parfait » est une phrase négative qui suit la construction normale." Même en admettant "Le pronom « personne » est un auxiliaire négatif, qui a ici la fonction grammaticale de sujet."a n'a rien d'une construction normale de phrase négative. En français les "auxiliaires négatifs" sont des adverbes centraux.

Comment: @Evpok La phrase « personne n'est parfait » est parfaitement normale. Ça, j'en suis sûr. Je suis moins sûr de la terminologie grammaticale. J'ai suivi celle de l'article [ne du TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ne) qui recouvre à la fois des adverbes (« pas », « jamais »), des pronoms (« personne », « aucun ») et même une conjonction de coordination (« ni »). Si tu n'est pas d'accord avec cette terminologie, peux-tu m'expliquer pourquoi, de préférence avec une référence ?

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord parce que c'est ce qu'on m'a appris. Je vais déterrer mes cours pour trouver la référence, mais c'était dans le cadre de X' (un peu simplifié). L'idée était que la négation en français est marquée par le négatif "ne" et éventuellement un adverbe central (donc placé derrière le verbe conjugué). Dans le cas de ce genre de phrases, on ne les considère pas comme négatives.