# Est-il acceptable d'omettre « pas » ou « point » après un verbe à la forme négative sans complément ?

Tags: grammaire, négation

Il est acceptable (quoique peut-être un peu désuet) de ne pas mettre de « pas » ou « point » après un verbe à la forme négative :

> Bon sang ne saurait mentir.

Cependant, quand le verbe n'est pas suivi d'un complément, l'absence de « pas » ou « point » me choque :

> Premier je suis, second je fus. Mouton ne change.

Dans la citation précédente, cette absence est-elle une licence prise par son auteur ou est-elle autorisée par la langue française ?

Comment: un sujet qui peut etre lié : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/301/lusage-de-ne-sans-un-mot-associ%C3%A9?rq=1, et http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/135/jai-bien-peur-que-tu-naies-raison-faut-il-mettre-le-mot-ne

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[L'article wiktionnaire sur pas](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pas#.C3.89tymologie) indique :

> #### Étymologie
>
> (*Nom*) Du latin passus (« *pas, enjambée, marche* » ou « *trace de pas* »).
>
> - (*Adverbe*) De l’usage en ancien français d’ajouter un substantif signifiant « *le moindre* » après *ne* :
>
>   > *Je ne bois goutte. — Je ne mange mie. — Je ne marche pas.*
> - L’usage de pas s’est généralisé par un cycle de Jespersen et la négation *ne* est pour sa part devenue optionnelle dans le langage courant :
>
>   > *Je marche pas dans cette combine. — J’vois pas où tu veux en venir.*

Ta première affirmation est donc correcte.

---

[L'article sur ne](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne#fr-part) donne plusieurs cas :

> 1. Négation. Première partie d’un morphème **en général** à double forme encadrant le verbe et certains pronoms. Parfois appelé discordantiel, *ne* est complété d’un forclusif : *pas*, *plus*, *jamais*, *point*, *personne*, *rien*, *aucun*, *nul*, etc., ou de formules archaïsantes : *goutte*, *mie*, *mais* (*n’en pouvoir mais*).
>
>    > *Je ne mange pas.*
> 2. Il s’emploie encore sans la particule *pas* quand la proposition renferme un pronom, un adjectif ou un adverbe négatifs.
>
>    > *Il ne sait rien.*
> 3. L’ordre est inversé dans le cas où le pronom négatif (personne, rien, aucun, nul) est en position sujet.
>
>    > *Que personne ne bouge.*
> 4. S’emploie seul aussi dans les propositions subordonnées quand la proposition principale est négative ou interrogative.
>
>    > *Il n’est pas d’homme qui ne désire être heureux.*
> 5. Il peut aussi s’employer encore seul avec certains verbes comme *cesser*, *oser*, *pouvoir*, *savoir* dans un langage soutenu, mais le langage courant ajoute presque systématiquement la particule *pas* (la seule conservée dans le langage familier) :
>
>    > *Il ne cesse de parler. (pour : Il ne cesse pas de parler.)*
> 6. Suffit parfois seul à marquer la négation, à la façon de la langue ancienne, dans les vieux tours ou en langue soutenue, comme :
>
>    > *N’importe ! (locution figée pour : Cela n’importe pas !)*
>    >
>    > *N’aie crainte. (locution figée pour : N’aie aucune crainte.)*
> 7. Employé seul, il a un sens explétif, dans ce cas il n’a pas de sens négatif, mais signale simplement un contexte négatif.
> 8. (*Vieilli*) S’emploie encore (de façon aujourd’hui optionnelle) dans certains cas archaïques mais encore rencontrés où, bien que la proposition secondaire ait la forme affirmative, la phrase entière renferme une idée négative. Il en est ainsi :
>
>    - Après les verbes qui expriment la crainte.
>
>      > *Je crains qu’il ne vienne.* (exprime aussi : *Je désire qu’il ne vienne pas*.)
>    - Après le verbe empêcher.
>
>      > *Empêche qu’il ne tombe,* (exprime aussi : *Il ne faut pas qu’il tombe.*)
>    - Dans certaines phrases qui expriment une comparaison, après plus que, moins que, mieux que, autre que.
>
>      > *Il est plus riche qu’on ne croit. (exprime aussi : Il n’est pas aussi pauvre qu’on le croit.)*
>    - Après les locutions conjonctives avant que, depuis que.
>
>      > *Finissez votre ouvrage avant que je ne revienne.*
>
> ---
>
> **Note**
>
> - La véritable particule de négation *pas* s’omet totalement dans toutes les propositions niées, en cas d’utilisation de la conjonction de coordination négative *ni* qui absorbe aussi le sujet mais n’absorbe normalement pas la particule réductrice verbale *ne* :
>
>   > *Je ne veux ni ne peux le faire. signifie : Je ne veux pas et je ne peux pas le faire.*

---

Dans le cas de ta citation :

> « Premier je suis, second je fus. Mouton ne change. »

On peut utiliser le point **8.** car il s'agit de la devise du [Château Mouton Rothschild](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A2teau_Mouton_Rothschild#Histoire_du_ch.C3.A2teau).

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. J'aurais effectivement dû consulter Wikipedia avant. La citation ne rentre dans aucune des dix catégories mentionnées par l'article (à part peut-être la 8ème - mais la citation n'est pas à l'impératif, ou la 10ème - mais la phrase ne renferme pas « d'idée négative »), ça me conforte dans l'idée que l'auteur de la citation a pris quelques libertés.

Comment: @GaTTaCa J'étais en train de chercher d'autres sources et d'ajouter une conclusion pour indiquer que ta citation correspondait à la 8, même si elle n'est pas à l'impératif. Il s'agit de la devise des [Château Mouton Rothschild](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A2teau_Mouton_Rothschild).

Answer (score 4):

Cette devise n'est pas incorrecte mais sa forme est en effet une variante désuète et poétique pour « Un (cru de) **Mouton** (Rothschild) **ne change** pas ».

Le Baron Philippe de Rothschild s'est inspiré du style utilisé dans les devises de l'ancien régime pour la devise initiale « **Premier ne puis, second ne daigne, Mouton suis** » puis celle modifiée ensuite quand sa production a fini par être reconnue comme un Premier Cru de Bordeaux.

Comment: Il ne s'agit donc pas d'un *ne* explétif (cas 8 cité plus haut), mais bien d'une omission du *pas*.

Comment: @XouDo Oui, absolument. La réponse acceptée est incorrecte, c'est frustrant mais ça arrive...