# "Où j'ai mordu dans plus que je ne pouvais mâcher"? (traduction de "My Way")

Tags: traduction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [J'ai bien peur que tu n'aies raison : faut-il mettre le mot « ne »?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/135/jai-bien-peur-que-tu-naies-raison-faut-il-mettre-le-mot-ne)

C'est la traduction de la phrase "When I bit off more than I could chew" de la chanson "My Way". A quoi sert-il de mettre le "ne" avant de "pouvais"? Il me semble que cela devient "more than I could not chew", et ce n'a pas de sens.

Comment: C'est une traduction un peu trop litérale à mon goût, si on me demande mon avis. Pour référence, une bonne expression pourrait être "avoir les yeux plus grands que le ventre" - mais ça n'est pas une réponse à la question.

Comment: J'aurais juré que l'original, c'était _Comme d'habitude_, voir p.e. [une comparaison de traductions avec l'original](http://www.nakedtranslations.com/en/2004/my-way)

Comment: En passant, une meilleure traduction de l'expression anglaise, serait d'utiliser _avoir les yeux plus grands que le ventre_.

Comment: @Joubarc Oui, ça me donne la réponse, merci!

Comment: @Unfrancophone l'original est bien `Comme d'habitude`.

Comment: @Joubarc Je ne pense pas que cette expression a le meme sens que l'expression anglaise. Dans une situation culinaire, c'est tres similaire, mais metaphoriquement, l'original a le sens que j'ai surestime mes capabilites, ta traduction a le sens que j'etais trop avide, ce qui marche pas tres bien avec le travail.

Comment: @Phira L'expression « [avoir les yeux plus gros que le ventre](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/380/avoir-les-yeux-plus-gros-que-le-ventre/) » a le même sens figuré de « se surestimer ». (En plus nous étions 2 à le dire spontanément, pourquoi juste moi? ;-))

Comment: @Joubarc "Bite off more than you can chew" has a strong overtone of work, you took on more tasks than you are capable of. The French phrase does not have the sense of work, you want too much to eat because eating is pleasurable. These overtones of work versus pleasure (through greed) are opposites. I was addressing this to you, because you are the first to answer. Why should I care about a copycat comment? Sorry for using English, but I obviously did not choose the correct French words to explain the difference above.

Comment: @Phira Don't worry, your French was perfectly understandable. It doesnt' change my opinion: the French expression can be used for work too, but if the English one is only about work, then yes there's a difference: the French one is more generic. The French expression is NOT just about food and you would be mistaken to believe so. Just because it uses food-specific terms doesn't mean it can't be used metaphorically too. (If that was so, it would be valid for the English one as well). Last thing, the "pourquoi juste moi?" part of my comment was just in jest, no need to worry about that.