# Why is there a "ne" here?

Tags: anglais, grammaire, négation

> **This question is a duplicate of:**
>   [J'ai bien peur que tu n'aies raison : faut-il mettre le mot « ne »?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/135/jai-bien-peur-que-tu-naies-raison-faut-il-mettre-le-mot-ne)

I'm reading a novel, here's part of it:

> Tout essoufflée, Elle atteint enfin la porte massive des appartements des femmes, le haremlik, gardé par deux eunuques soudanais coiffés d'un fez écarlate. Aujourd’hui il y a peu de visites et ils se sont assis pour converser plus à l’aise. À la vue de la «petite sultane», ils se lèvent précipitamment, entrouvrent le vantail de bronze et la saluent avec d’autant plus de respect qu’ils craignent qu’elle ne rapporte leur indolence.

Translated into English, I guess it's something like this:

> Breathless, she finally reached the massive door of the women's apartments, the haremlik, guarded by two Sudanese eunuchs wearing a fez scarlet. Today there are few visits and they sat down to talk more at ease. In view of the "little sultana," they rise precipitously, they halfway opened the door of bronze and greet with all the more respect (because) they fear she will report their indolence.

Now, the last line, “*ils craignent qu’elle ne rapporte leur indolence*”, why there is a *ne* here? Isn't that *ne* means *not*?
So if “they fear she will report their indolence”, literally, it shall be
“*ils craignent qu’elle rapporte leur indolence*”, right?

Do I make some mistake here,… or there's a locution?

Comment: Both are correct, this question has already been asked — and answered. See http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/135/jai-bien-peur-que-tu-naies-raison-faut-il-mettre-le-mot-ne

Comment: You are welcome. I am sorry that there is still no translation for this faq (there's already several duplicates). I'll try to make one if I can find some time.

Comment: no problem. i did get the answer! :) thanks for your time.