# Quelle est la différence entre « ne », « ne … pas » et « pas » ?

Tags: grammaire, négation

Quelle est la différence entre *ne*, *ne … pas* et *pas* ?

Par exemple :

> J'ai peur qu'il ne vienne pas.
>
> J'ai peur qu'il vienne pas.
>
> J'ai peur qu'il ne vienne.

Comment: Une réponse partielle se trouve ici : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/135/jai-bien-peur-que-tu-naies-raison-faut-il-mettre-le-mot-ne

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> J'ai peur qu'il ne vienne pas

Ta crainte est qu'il ne vienne pas. Tu es alors inquiet pour lui (il lui est peut-être arrivé quelque chose), ou c'est juste une déception.

---

> J'ai peur qu'il vienne pas

Le sens est le même que l'exemple précédent. Attention, il est incorrect à l'écrit, mais accepté à l'oral, dans un registre familier.

---

> J'ai (bien) peur qu'il ne vienne

À l'opposé, ta crainte est alors qu'il vienne. Là où *J'ai peur qu'il vienne* exprime une réelle inquiétude, presque la terreur, cette forme exprime alors plus le regret, la résignation, accentuée par la présence optionnelle du *bien*. Il s'agit alors d'un ne [explétif](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expl%C3%A9tif#La_semi-n.C3.A9gation_.C2.AB_ne_.C2.BB), ou semi-négation.

Comment: C'est une très excellente réponse.

Answer (score -1):

Je ne jamais dit « ne » quand je parle, mais quelquefois je l'ecris.

C'est correct a mettre, mais c'est comprehensible sans « ne ».