# Négation en français courant

Tags: négation

Quand est ce que je peux retirer le "ne" négatif en français courant ? par exemple, je dis "je n'ai pas vérifié" ou "j'ai pas vérifié" ?

Comment: Welcome to FSE. I edited your question. You don't need say thanks, bonjour, and the like when you ask questions:-)! Also when you use inverted commas (instead of the French 'guillemets') you don't leave space between the word or the sentence and the inverted commas.

Answer (score 7):

Quand tu parles à un professeur de français, à une autorité, quand tu fais un discours :

> Je n'ai pas vérifié.

Quand tu parles à des collègues, des amis, à ta famille :

> J'ai pas vérifié.

Si tu n'es pas sûr(e) :

> Je n'ai pas vérifié.

Personne ne va te reprocher d'avoir utilisé ce *ne*.

Comment: Je pense que le point primordial ici, c'est que c'est accepté à l'oral. A l'écrit, par contre, cela me semble très douteux.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Oui, il faut plutôt parler de registre de langue, ce que fait la question: *français courant*, *comment je dis*. Comme l'a répondu Dimitris, à l'écrit relâché (ex: textos), le *ne* est couramment omis.

Answer (score 3):

Non locuteur natif du français. Normalement, lors d'un discours  relâché, d'une discussion relâchée ou d'un texto on peut retirer le "ne". Les locuteurs natifs le font d'ailleurs.

> J'ai pas vérifié.

Note qu'il existe quand même des locuteurs natifs qui considèrent cet assouplissement grammatical incorrect.
Par conséquent je te propose de ne pas l'utiliser si tu n'en est pas sûr(e).

Question connexe : [Quelle est la différence entre « ne », « ne … pas » et « pas » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6604/quelle-est-la-diff%c3%a9rence-entre-ne-ne-pas-et-pas)

**NB :** Note aussi que, contrairement à ce que l'on dit, en langage  littéraire c'est la particule *pas* qui est facultative (dans quelques cas exceptionnels ; voir ci-après).

> Je ne sais pas quoi faire/Je sais pas quoi faire/J'sais pas quoi faire => **Je ne sais que faire**.

Les cas exceptionnels :

> L’adverbe ne s’emploie seul (langue littéraire) que :
>
> - dans certains proverbes et expressions :
>   Qui ne dit mot consent.
>   Qu’à cela ne tienne ;
> - avec les verbes avoir, savoir et pouvoir suivi de que interrogatif
>   et d’un infinitif :
>   Il ne sait que dire = Il ne sait pas quoi dire ;
> - avec les verbes cesser, pouvoir et savoir :
>   Je ne saurais vous dire. = Je ne saurais pas vous dire

Source : https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ne-sans-pas-savoir-pouvoir-oser-cesser.1944755/

Comment: « pas » n'est omis que dans des cas très particuliers, seulement quelques verbes  « choisis » : savoir, pouvoir, …

Answer (score 0):

Vous dites comme vous le voulez en vous rappelant pour faire votre décision que
1/ il n'y a rien de faux grammaticalement dans la préservation de « ne » dans tous les cas,
2/ dans les propos assez formels cette particule est le plus souvent préservée,
3/ une grande majorité des gens ne préservent pas cette particule dans leur parler de tous les jours et que parmi ceux-ci beaucoup sont énervés lorsqu'ils entendent quelqu'un qui ne fait pas comme eux,
4/ ne pas préserver la particule dans le parler courant rend plus difficile, moins naturel de l'utiliser lorsque l'on a le faire par exemple dans une prise de parole où on est restreint à être assez formel,
5/ dans le texte écrit il est considéré comme une erreur de ne pas l'utiliser, sauf lorsque l'on rapporte les paroles de quelqu'un.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais vu personne qui soit énervé par le *ne* de quelqu'un d'autre. Tu veux peut-être dire quelqu'un d'énervé quand on le reprend alors que lui-même n'a pas dit ce *ne*.

Comment: @jlliagre Non, je veux dire que les gens font des réflexions qui montrent clairement qu'ils désapprouvent cette habitude, montrent qu'ils n'aiment pas ça. Ce sont les gens qui ont inspiré  Brassens dans son  « Non, les bonnes gens n'aiment pas que l'on suive un autre chemin qu'eux. ».

Comment: C'est le contraire. Les "**braves** gens" de Brassens sont des conformistes, donc plutôt du côté de ceux qui prônent la présence de *ne* alors que celui qui a la mauvaise réputation se fiche des normes, y compris celle de la métrique.

Comment: @jlliagre On met les bonnes gens où on le veut !

Comment: 1. Brassens parle (ironiquement) de **braves** gens, pas de **bonnes** gens. 2. Si tu penses qu'un anarchiste, antimilitariste, anticonformiste qui défend les voleurs de poules s'appliquera à utiliser le *ne* de la négation, tu n'as pas compris Brassens.

Comment: @jlliagre https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/gens/36606 Bonnes gens, braves gens, personnes simples, sans malice.

Comment: @LPH il est dangereux de se servir de textes de chanson pour y trouver des règles de grammaire. Certains s'y permettent tout (c'est aussi le cas dans les textes anglais, d'ailleurs). Example: Renaud à sorti une chanson récemment qu'il a titré "Les Animals"...

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Je ne prétend pas du tout m'occuper de grammaire en citant Brassens; je fais seulement une petite remarque soulignant un état d'esprit qui confirme l'attitude d'un assez grand nombre de personnes. Il me semble qu'il est important d'avoir une idée de l'effet que notre utilisation personnelle du langage peut avoir sur les autres; c'est tout.

Comment: Ok, donc je renouvelle mon étonnement car tu parles de *beaucoup* puis d'un *assez grand nombre de personnes* alors que je n'ai jamais vu personne qui soit énervé par l'utilisation de ce *ne* par quelqu'un d'autre.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est assez difficile à évaluer; il est certain que ces gens ne représentent pas un groupe très nombreux; il y a sans aucun doute un très grand groupe qui n'a aucune réaction de quelque sorte que ce soit, indépendamment de ce qu'ils pensent. Ce n'est pas un phénomène qui se constate seulement dans le cas de l'usage de cette particule, mais il dépend du  même état d'esprit qui existe en  matières de toutes sortes de comportements. Disons qu' une section non négligeable  de la population  est affectée de cette façon; je n'insisterais pas sur mon évaluation au pied de la lettre.