# « Avant qu’en un chœur sans pareil n’éclate La Marseillaise » : n'éclate ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, négation

Dans le discours d'Emmanuel Macron du 11 nov 2018, il y a une phrase:

> Souvenons-nous, nous autres Français, de ce que Clemenceau a proclamé le jour de la victoire, il y a cent ans jour pour jour, du haut de la tribune de l’Assemblée nationale, avant qu’en un chœur sans pareil n’éclate La Marseillaise : ...

Pourquoi « n'éclate » ? Que signifie cette forme négative ?

Comment: [Cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/135/16656) présente le `ne` explétif, ça fait peut-être doublon avec ce sujet ?

Comment: C'est très certainement un *ne explétif*, mais ici il n'a pas vraiment la même fonction que dans l'autre question. J'ai ma petite idée, mais j'avoue que je serais intrigué d'en savoir plus, si quelqu'un sait préciser et généraliser sa raison d'être dans des cas comme ça.

Comment: Merci beaucoup de votre réponse. Je peux bien comprendre cette phrase maintenant. Merci

Answer (score 1):

Pour répondre à la demande de Stéphane Gimenez en commentaires dans l'OP. (*"il n'a pas vraiment la même fonction que dans l'autre question... généraliser sa raison d'être*"...)

Le *ne explétif* a, dans cette phrase comme dans l'autre, très précisément la même fonction, la même raison d'être... c'est à dire : **aucune**!

Grevisse, le tenant pour rigoureusement inutile, le traite de *"parasite"*. Littré se contente de le dire *"surabondant"*. Pour Vendryes, il est carrément *"abusif"*

Certains diront que c'est (pour l'autre exemple) l'expression de la crainte dans la principale qui en *dicte* la présence dans la complétive et que dans le cas de cette question c'est la conjonction *avant-que* qui en dicte la présence dans la conjonctive.

D'autres argumenteront que c'est en fait l'utilisation du subjonctif (mode du non-jugement par excellence) dans la subordonnée qui en commande la présence.
Au même titre que le *que*, ce *ne explétif* ne serait donc rien d'autre dans ces deux exemples qu'une des *béquilles* d'un subjonctif qui ne sait que très rarement se passer d'accessoires.

- En appui de cet argument (qui représente une opinion que je partage), on notera la réalité qu'il n'apparaît jamais dans des complétives dont le verbe est conjugué à l'indicatif.

...avant que **n** 'éclate... soit! Mais
...après qu'il se fut emparé du micro.

L'observation de la langue ne permet en tout cas pas de *généraliser* les circonstances de son emploi.

Certes Molière écrit-il dans l'avare :

*J'ai peur qu'un homme de mon âge **ne soit** pas de son goût et que cela **ne vienne** à produire chez moi...*

Mais dans Dom Juan :

*J'ai peur qu'elle **ne soit** mal payée de son amour, que son voyage en cette ville **produise** peu de fruit et que vous **eussiez** autant gagné...*

Si vous aviez trouvé des pistes pour généraliser... bhein... elle deviennent tout de suite un peu moisies. ;-)

---

Hors sujet : Note que je m'attendais bien plutôt à ce que les maniaques du subjonctif questionnent ici la pertinence d'un présent pour *éclate* après le passé composé de *a déclaré*...

Comment: Je penses que tu rates la portée exclamative de ce *ne* là, qui ne se retrouve pas dans les autres exemples. Et pour le hors sujet, le passé composé est un présent pour la concordance. Certes, c’eût été différent s'il eût employé un passé simple.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : le PC un présent pour la concordance ? Taratatère! Pas pour les maniaques. Pour eux PC + Subj PRE est au contraire un cas de **non** concordance. (Pourtant bienvenu... à mon opinion). Pour la portée exclamative, je veux bien admettre que je l'ai ratée... car... même après relecture suite à ton observation, je ne la trouve toujours pas.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : Dis-moi! À propos de ta *portée exclamative* c'est à Lacan que tu penses ? Si tel est le cas, je veux bien augmenter ma contrib d'un nota + référence sur ce sujet, bien sérieux il est vrai mais qui, je dois l'avouer, m'est totalement étranger et dépasse peut-être le cadre de FSE. (Mais c'est toi le modo)

Comment: Non, simple coïncidence :-)